# Несколько столбцов в CheckListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в vs2010 c# winforms выполнить следующую задачу:
На `Form1` есть `CheckListBox1` и кнопка `button_add`, с помощью которой происходит добавление строк в `CheckListBox1` из `DataGridView1` (состоящего из 3-х столбцов), расположенного на форме `Form2`. Кодом ниже получается добавить строку в `CheckListBox1` только из выбранной строки 1-го столбца `DataGridView1` (т.е. "`getItem()`"). Как сделать добавление значений из выбранной строки из 3-х столбцов `DataGridView1` в три столбца `CheckListBox1` соответственно?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CheckListBox1.Sorted = true;
            CheckListBox1.TopIndex = 0;
            CheckListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;
            CheckListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
            CheckListBox1.MultiColumn = true;
}

private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
                var form2 = new Form2();
                if (form2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    CheckListBox1.SetSelected(CheckListBox1.Items.Add(form2.getItem()), true);
                }
                form2.Close();
                form2.Dispose();
}
```

---

```
public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }

        //0столбец:
        public string getItem()
        {
            String Tab = (String)this.dataGridView1[0, this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value;
            return Tab;
        }
        //1столбец:
        public string getItem1()
        {
            String Tab1 = (String)this.dataGridView1[1, this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value;
            return Tab1;
        }
        //2столбец:
        public string getItem2()
        {
            String Tab2 = (String)this.dataGridView1[2, this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value;
            return Tab2;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public List<string> GetItems()
 {
   List<string> lOut = new List<string>();
   foreach(DataGridViewColumn item in dataGridView1.Columns)
{lOut.Add((String)this.dataGridView1[dataGridView1.Columns[item.Name].Index,dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value;
            }
   return lOut;
 }



private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var form2 = new Form2();
  if (form2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
  {
     var lst =GetItems();
     foreach (var item in lst)
     {
        CheckListBox1.SetSelected(CheckListBox1.Items.Add(item, true);
     }

  }
  form2.Close();
  form2.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: В коде button_add_Click появляется ошибка "Элемент "GetItems" не существует в текущем контексте".

Comment: @olga поместите этот метод в класс `Form2` и вызовите его form2.GetItems();

Comment: Теперь на строке "foreach(DataColumn item in dataGridView1.Columns)" появляется ошибка "Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn" к типу "System.Data.DataColumn".

Comment: @olga подправил метод немного